# Applet не компилируется

Tags: applet, java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
/*
<applet code= "MouseEvents" width=300 height=100>
</applet>
*/
public class MouseEvent extends Applet
implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
String msg = "";
int mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
public void init() {
addMouseListener(this);
addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
mouseX = 0;
mouseY = 10;
msg = "mouse clicked.";
msg = "KHO/7KA MbIWbI";
repaint();
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me){
mouseX = 0;
mouseY = 10;
msg = "mouse entered.";
msg = "KYPCOP MbIWbI BOWE7";
repaint();
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me){
mouseX = 0;
mouseY = 10;
msg = "mouse exited.";
msg = "KYPCOP MbIWbI BbIWE7";
repaint();
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){
mouseX = me.getX();
mouseY = me.getY();
msg = "DOWN.";
msg = "BHU3";
repaint();
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){
mouseX = me.getX();
mouseY = me.getY();
msg = "UP.";
msg = "BBEPX";
repaint();
}
public void mouseDragged((MouseEvent me){
mouseX = me.getX();
mouseY = me.getY();
msg = "*";
ShowStatus("Dragging mouse at " +mouseX+ ", " +mouseY);
ShowStatus("/7EPETACKUBANUE MbIWbI B " +mouseX+ ", " +mouseY);
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
g.drawString(msg, mouseX, mouseY);
}
}

mouseEvent.java:9 MouseEvent is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener
public class MouseEvent extends Applet
       ^
1 error
load: class MouseEvent not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MouseEvent
```

В чём ошибка?Пример с учебника.Linux, jdk 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам же компилятор все сообщает на человеческом языке.

Во-первых, имя файла без расширения должно совпадать с именем основного класса в файле. Т.е. имя файла должно быть `MouseEvent.java`, а не `mouseEvent.java`.

Во-вторых, ваш класс реализует интерфейс `MouseListener`, который определяет ряд методов, в том числе `mouseExited`. Вы обязаны либо реализовать этот метод, либо сделать его абстрактным. О чем и сообщает компилятор. Хотя метод и содержится в вашем коде, он не соответствует по сигнатуре аналогичному методу из интерфейса `MouseListener`, т.к. `java.awt.event.MouseEvent` и ваш класс `MouseEvent` - это разные типы данных. По умолчанию компмилятор пытается использовать класс из текущего пакета, а не из `java.awt.event`.

В-третьих, предвосхищая возможные вопросы в будущем, скажу, что это касается и остальных методов реализуемых интерфейсов. Кроме того у вас не хватае реализации метода `mouseMoved`, лишня скобочка в м объявлении метода `mouseDragged` и два вызова несуществующего метода `ShowStatus`.